# How to switch bluetooth on/off using Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am new to Swift, and trying to learn communicating with bluetooth and wifi.

I went through many online tutorials but they seems only teaching how to initiate centralDeviceManager and scan and connect to a device, and also checking for the status, but I can't find out how to enable/disable bluetooth. I got this in my viewController.swift file. Can anyone please suggest me how to enable it please.

```
import CoreBluetooth

class ProfileListViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,CBPeripheralDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate {

var manager:CBCentralManager!
    var peripheral:CBPeripheral!
    let BEAN_NAME = "Robu"
    let BEAN_SCRATCH_UUID =
        CBUUID(string: "bb2819df-f8ef-4f90-811e-20a4f53eb949")
    let BEAN_SERVICE_UUID =
        CBUUID(string: "bb2819df-f8ef-4f90-811e-20a4f53eb949")

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager){
        print("CentralManager is initialized")

        switch central.state{
        case CBManagerState.unauthorized:
            print("The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth low energy.")
        case CBManagerState.poweredOff:
            print("Bluetooth is currently powered off.")
        case CBManagerState.poweredOn:
            print("Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use.")
        default:break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for security resons apple wont allow to switch on / off  bluetooth . by manually you can do that.

Comment: Hi @Ramkumarchintala is this same for Wifi, Airplane mode, Mobile Data, Location Service, Do not Disturb. settings that the user can't programmatically enable/disable them?

Comment: yes same for all you mentioned

Comment: Thank your Piyush bhai, damn I was planning to create an app which allows user to maintain a profile with all this settings and then schedule them with time and week days to automatically enable it, like old nokia phones.

Comment: @Keyur : Thank god that you are just "planning"...:D

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not allow enabling or disabling bluetooth programmatically.

The best practice would be to show an alert, when bluetooth is required and ask the user to turn it on.